# Prevent Menu Items from being deleted or moved

Tags: routes, hooks

How can I prevent certain menu links (i.e. Home, About, Contact) in the "Home » Administration » Structure » Menus" section from being deleted from a menu. I want to prevent clients from deleting the Homepage. Eventually, I would like to prevent them from moving or reordering the Homepage as well. I was hoping that there are hooks where I could query that if the node id is a certain value, that I could cancel the deletion (or move).

Comment: Are there other links in the same menu that you want your clients to be able to modify/move around?  Or are you looking for permissions per menu (tree)?

Comment: nmc is on to something. What I do is set permissions per-menu with [Menu per role](http://drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) to prevent clients from accidentally altering information that is vital to the site's structure by hiding certain menu items (for clients that admittedly don't want to mess anything up). Then i tell them they're free to alter what I've made available to them. Would that be enough?

Comment: nmc - Yes, I want admins to be able to move all the pages under the top level page (ie. Home, About, Contact). I do not want them to move or delete About.

Comment: jordojuice - I'll try out Menu per role.

Comment: jordojuice - Menu per role did not work the way I wanted. It hid the items off the main menu.